# How to pass a data frame through a function and return another data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have a data frame with real estate information about the neighborhood, type of property, type of negotiation, and price. It looks like this:

```
**neighborhood type_property type_negotiation price**
Smallville       house           rent        2000
Oakville       apartment       for sale      100000
King Bay         house         for sale      250000
    . 
    .
```

What I want to do is pass this through a function that sort the data frame by neighborhood I enter into it, if its a house, if its for sale, the number of properties that fit these requirements, and also gives the 90th percentile and 10th percentile.

The function and code I have so far is below, but I keep running into multiple syntax and other errors:

```
def function(string):
    a = df[(df.type_negotiation == 'for sale')&(df.type_property == 'house')&(df.neighborhood == string)
    b = pd.new_df([a.price.quantile(.10),a.price.quantile(.90),a.shape], columns=('tenthpercentile','ninetiethpercentile','Quantity'))
    return b
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: what syntax errors are you getting? and in your function you're not passing in a dataframe. Also where did you get `pd.new_df` from ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code:

1. Use `pd.DataFrame` constructor to construct a new dataframe.
2. As a 2-dimensional object, you should feed a *list of lists* into the constructor. Notice the double open and close square brackets.
3. For the length of a dataframe, use `len(a)` or `len(a.index)` or `a.shape[0]`. `a.shape` returns a size-2 tuple representing the number of rows and columns. Incidentally, this ties in well with the requirement in (2).

At the end of this, you will get a single-row dataframe:

```
def foo(string):
    a = df[(df.type_negotiation == 'forsale')&(df.type_property == 'house')&(df.neighborhood == string)]
    b = pd.DataFrame([[a.price.quantile(0.1), a.price.quantile(0.9), len(a.index)]],
                     columns=('tenthpercentile', 'ninetiethpercentile', 'Quantity'))
    return b

print(foo('KingBay'))

   tenthpercentile  ninetiethpercentile  Quantity
0         250000.0             250000.0         1
```

A more idiomatic and generalized solution, include your dataframe as an input parameter to your function and utilize [`pd.DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html):

```
def foo(df, string):
    # as before

df.pipe(foo, 'KingBay')
```

Comment: Would you know how to loop this function so that it goes through and performs this action for every neighborhood, then put the single row data frames together? I have tried putting a for loop around the function, but it just prints out the list of neighborhood names I have.

Comment: @MateoSundberg, Well, yes. But a good solution to *that* question would be *very* different to the answer to your question here. I recommend you ask as a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), giving your current attempt as it stands.